# Netty Handle HTTP requests

Tags: netty

I am writing an HTTP server using netty which will recive an http webservice request. Taking reference from the [SnoopServer Example](http://netty.io/4.0/xref/io/netty/example/http/snoop/package-summary.html), I was able to get the request in my HTTP handler. Now should I write a backend servlet based application( for ex: using tomcat) to process that request or a should I handle that in my netty handler code either using switch case or something else?

Which approach is more suitable? If both are wrong, then is there any other approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write a backend servlet application then **what is the point of using Netty as a backend for your application ?**

You could have used either one for receiving the HTTP requests and handling them. Since you are experimenting with Netty, you should handle the HTTP request inside the handler itself and then send out HTTP response from there only. Using tomcat would be an overkill.

Comment: This is an actual production scenario. I need to decide the way to handle HTTP requests once netty's http handler gets them.  The reason of using Netty is that my server needs to handle both custom TCP requests as well as HTTP requests

Comment: Then what you could also do is that is to start your servlet based backend as another service and as and when you receive requests in your Netty handler, you can handle them in an async manner by passing them to the other server along with a callback.